# How to insert column in SQL Server dynamically using stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying this query but its not working.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_UPDATEUSERS_0 
    @COLUMNNAME NVARCHAR(30),
    @DATATYPE NVARCHAR(30) 
AS 
    ALTER TABLE HC_USER_MAIN 
      ADD COLUMNNAME = @COLUMNNAME DATATYPE = @DATATYPE
```

but I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure USP_UPDATEUSERS_0, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Did you look up the syntax to add a column?

Comment: This has "Bad design" written all over it. Why would you want a stored procedure to be executing DDL statements in the first place?

Comment: Why bother with a procedure at all. I don't see how executing                  `EXECUTE USP_UPDATEUSERS_0 'NewColumn', 'VARCHAR(50)`, is any more convenient than  `ALTER TABLE HC_USER_MAIN ADD NewColumn VARCHAR(50)`

Comment: Fully agree with @ZoharPeled too, if you are adding new columns often enough to warrant a stored procedure to do it, then this is a serious code smell.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with the help of dynamic SQL (and better use `sysname` for this):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_UPDATEUSERS_0 
  @COLUMNNAME sysname,
  @DATATYPE sysname 
AS 
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
--To check if column with that name not exists
IF NOT EXISTS(
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'HC_USER_MAIN' and COLUMN_NAME = @COLUMNNAME)
--If not exists then add new column
SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE HC_USER_MAIN ADD ' + QUOTENAME(@COLUMNNAME) + ' ' + @DATATYPE
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Not that I agree with the answer, but you should at least use `QUOTENAME` rather than just simply concatenating brackets, it would properly escape the column name if someone sent something like  `Test] INT; DROP TABLE HC_USER_MAIN;--`.

Comment: Just thought about this ether.

Comment: So, does my answer help you? Did you check it?